# dynamic canvas shapes Not filling with color

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a canvas That use's width and height measurements to dynamically draw the front view of a house or similar structure. With the formulas i use i can get the front view drawn but cannot get to fillStyle or fill() to work. The color will be dynamic with a drop down once i figure out why its not adding the fill color.

http://jsfiddle.net/steven27030/0syb9LLh/

HTML

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Hit Me</button>
<button id="colorbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Color Me</button>
<button id="sizebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Try it</button>
<br>
<br>
<p>
    <select id="width" class="width" name="width"></select>
</p>
<p>
    <select id="height" class="height" name="height"></select>
</p>
<div id="here"></div>
```

CSS

```
    canvas {
    margin: 25px;
}
button {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
select {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sizebtn").click(function () {
        var result;
        var i;
        var j;
        var feet = 30;
        var inches = 12;
        for (i = 0; i < feet; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < inches; j++) {
                if (j < 10) {
                    result += '<option value="' + i + '.0' + j + '">' + i + '.0' + j + '</option>';
                } else {
                    result += '<option value="' + i + '.' + j + '">' + i + '.' + j + '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        result += '<option value="30.00">30.00</option>';
        $('select.width').html(result);
        $("select.width").val("12.00");
    });

    $("#sizebtn").click(function () {
        var result;
        var i;
        var j;
        var feet = 500;
        var inches = 12;
        for (i = 0; i < feet; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < inches; j++) {
                if (j < 10) {
                    result += '<option value="' + i + '.0' + j + '">' + i + '.0' + j + '</option>';
                } else {
                    result += '<option value="' + i + '.' + j + '">' + i + '.' + j + '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        result += '<option value="500.00">500.00</option>';
        $('select.length').html(result);
        $("select.length").val("21.00");
    });

    $("#sizebtn").click(function () {
        var result;
        var i;
        var j;
        var feet = 12;
        var inches = 12;
        for (i = 0; i < feet; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < inches; j++) {
                if (j < 10) {
                    result += '<option value="' + i + '.0' + j + '">' + i + '.0' + j + '</option>';
                } else {
                    result += '<option value="' + i + '.' + j + '">' + i + '.' + j + '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        result += '<option value="12.00">12.00</option>';
        $('select.height').html(result);
        $("select.height").val("5.00");
    });

});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var canvasWidth = $("#myCanvas").width();
        var canvasHeight = $("#myCanvas").height();
        var selwidth = $('#width').val();
        var selheight = $('#height').val();
        var middle = canvasWidth / 2;
        var percentage = 90 / 100;
        var max_size = canvasWidth * percentage;
        var ftWidth = parseInt(max_size, 10) / 30;
        var InWidth = parseInt(ftWidth, 10) / 12;
        var halfFoot = 6 * InWidth;
        var frameWidth = selwidth * ftWidth;
        var frameFromTop = selheight * ftWidth;
        var frameHeight = canvasHeight - frameFromTop;
        var base = (canvasWidth - frameWidth) / 2;
        var baseSixInche = base - (InWidth * 6);
        var leftoverhangHeight = (frameHeight + .125);
        //var peakHeight = ();
        var rightoverhang = base + frameWidth + (InWidth * 6);
        var rightLeg = frameWidth + base;
        var rise = 3 * InWidth;
        var riserun = (frameWidth / 2) / 12;
        var peak = frameHeight - (rise * riserun);
        var tubeSize = 2.5 * InWidth;
        var roofTrim = 3 * InWidth;
        var sideTrim = 2.5 * InWidth;
        //var peak = (.5 * middle + canvasHeight - frameHeight);
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // Stroked triangle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(base, canvasHeight); // Start Point
        ctx.lineTo(base, frameHeight); // Left Leg
        ctx.moveTo(baseSixInche, leftoverhangHeight); // left overhang
        ctx.lineTo(middle, peak); // Peak
        ctx.moveTo(middle, peak); // Peak
        ctx.lineTo(rightoverhang, leftoverhangHeight); // Right overhang
        ctx.moveTo(rightLeg, canvasHeight); // Start Right Leg
        ctx.lineTo(rightLeg, frameHeight); // Right Leg
        ctx.moveTo(rightLeg, canvasHeight); //base
        ctx.lineTo(base, canvasHeight); // End Point

        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.lineWidth = tubeSize;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'silver';
        ctx.stroke();
        //alert(ctx.fill);
    });
});
```

This is a fiddle with my code. Just hit the try me button to fill the width and height drop downs dynamically. The select the size you want and click on Hit Me. Sorry for the weird button names but i was just experimenting so i did not put any thought in them until i use this code in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set an event handler for your `Color Me` button so no action is being taken when it's pressed.

**About your fill not appearing:**

You are creating your building with a series of line segments instead of a path. Since line segments can't be filled, ctx.fill() is being ignored.

If you want to create and fill the building, do one `moveTo` to get it started and then just use `lineTo`s to draw a single path.

One way to do that would be to

- draw the "pentagon" shape of the building itself (no overhangs)
- stroke and fill the pentagon
- draw the overhangs as strokes

Comment: i know but shouldnt the fillStyle and fill()  work in the event handler for the hit me button? i have that in the code above.

Comment: Ah...I see what you're saying now. See the addition to my answer. Cheers!

Comment: i see what you mean now. i just have to adjust my bad code a little. thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/steven27030/mfpt34jh/  i fixed it, if you know to fill it with horizontal gradient stripes like steel panels let me lol.

Comment: Actually, yes I do. You should take a look at `context.createPattern` which will take a single image and repeat that image to fill a path. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove those calls to `moveLine` and draw your shape as a continuous polygon for fill to work. Try this:

```js
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(base, canvasHeight);
ctx.lineTo(base, frameHeight);
ctx.lineTo(middle, peak);
ctx.lineTo(rightLeg, leftoverhangHeight);
ctx.lineTo(rightLeg, canvasHeight);
ctx.lineTo(base, canvasHeight);
ctx.closePath();
```

You can draw the awning separately after the fill is complete.

Comment: i wish i could select more than one answer you both where right